# Can a Pokémon relearn egg moves if it has been traded?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I am asking this because I don't currently have access to the game and would like to know for definite before planning any breeding projects. Plus, it'd be interesting to see how this aspect of Pokémon breeding works from a technical standpoint.

For example's sake, say I breed Wish onto Eevee. A little down the line I replace it with... draining kiss (provided evolving it into Sylveon doesn't delete the ability to relearn these egg moves) but then I decide I want to give it away to my friend over Wifi.

Would my friend then have the option of using a move relearner to re-obtain Wish, or are they out of luck?

Comment: The [pokemon-series] tag is unnecessary, please don't add it back.

Comment: How is it unnecessary? It's a Pokémon game. It was made for this purpose.

Comment: Wrong, as the name implies, it's made for questions about the series itself, not any specific game. Please read tags' descriptions before adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, egg moves are stored in their own special location in a Pokémon's data and cannot be overwritten or modified by anything except hacking.